# How can I call shell script from one container to another container and capture output without ssh in Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, ssh, monitor, docker-swarm

Is there any way to call shell script one container to another container and capture output and show that output in UI without ssh.

I have tried making password less containers but I am not able to scale the containers. If I am scaling that containers then password less ssh not working.

Comment: Mount the docker socket in the 'control' container and use `docker exec` to run a command on the second container.

Comment: @Johanharris85 Actually, I am calling a shell script from one container to another with password less login. Actually, I want to monitor services from A container to  B container and present the output on UI

Comment: Can you paste the shell script and / or give more info? If you need to do something in one container, from another container, either it's going to be network (ssh) or tooling (Docker). Are you expecting / thinking there is some other solution?